# For sales person (cost center) provision list of sales invoices paid

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online, invantive-sql

In Exact Online you can not easily determine what invoices have recently been paid and get a total on that to base our provision for the sales persons on. How can I get such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general ledger account code 1300 or some other interim account is used to post the unpaid sales invoices to. When they are moved outside of that interim account, you will know that they have been paid. You will need an Invantive SQL query like:

```
select costcenter
,      division
,      listagg(accountcode) lijstrelaties
,      sum(amountdc)
,      listagg(invoicenumber) facturen
from   transactionlines 
where  glaccountcode = '1300'
and    financialyear = year(sysdate)
and    financialperiod = month(sysdate)
group 
by     costcenter
,      division
```

You might need to specify additional that it is an outflow using for instance `amountdc < 0`. Now it sums both inflow and outflow.